# Restrict filtering of measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, measure

Can someone help me finding a way to restrict a measure getting filtered in Power BI?

I have a visual that displays the percentage of manual activities occurred in a particular region. The calculation done is

```
 RegionManualActivityCount*100/CountryManualActivityCount
```

I have around 10 regions in a country and I have wrote a general measure to do the calculation. In Power BI for each region's visual I have a visual filter applied based on Region Name. But the problem is the CountryManualActivityCount is also getting filtered based on Region Name. I do not want the CountryManualActivityCount in the measure calculation to be filtered.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the Dax function ALL or ALLEXCEPT to remove the applied filters to your report.
Something like `CALCULATE(Table,RegionManualActivityCount*100/CountryManualActivityCount,ALL(Table[RegionName]))`

It will remove your filters on Region Name in this particular measure.